# How do I remove eval() from the following code .... - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been using eval in my code and I recently found out that there can be serious security issues If eval() is used inside Javascript. The most common scenario is where I'm using eval() to compose a variable name and then get the value of that variable like here;

```
var a = "2"        // could be any value

work(a);

function work(a)
{
var l1 = "something";
var l2 = "something else";
var l3 = "something different";

alert(eval("l"+a));
// alerts "something else"
};
```

Are there any alternatives to eval() in a situation like this ??

I've tried using window["l"+a] but that will only work if the variables were global and also document.getElementById("l"+a) and that doesn't work either.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Norman.

Comment: Note that `eval` is only *dangerous* when you're letting the user enter something that gets evaluated. But it's also bad practice, and avoidable in 99.9% of cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

perhaps use an object or an array:

```
var obj = {
    '1' : 'something',
    '2' : 'something else',
    'foo' : 'entirely different'
};
// access like this:
obj[1];            // "something"
obj['foo'];        // "entirely different"
var key = 'foo';
obj[key];          // "entirely different"
```

or, as an array:

```
var arr = [
    "something",
    "something else",
    "something different"
];
arr[0] // something
arr[1] // something else
```

Comment: definately as the array. then the parameter is just an array index.

Comment: @Eric, yep I definitely agree that's the best option, though I wasn't sure whether the suffixed numbers were meaningful in the OP.

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
window["l"+a]
```

e.g.

```
var a = "2"        // could be any value

work(a);

function work(a)
{
l1 = "something";
l2 = "something else";
l3 = "something different";

alert(window["l"+a]);
// alerts "something else"
};
```

Alternatively, you could use an array or object notation (preferred as it doesn't pollute global)

```
var a = "2"        // could be any value

work(a);

function work(a)
{
var l = ["something", "something else", "something different" ];

alert(l[a]);
// alerts "something else"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

use a switch

```
function match(a)
{

 switch(a)
  {
  case 1:
   alert("something");
  break;
  case 2:
   alert("something else");
  break;
  case 3:
   alert("something different");
  break;
  default:
   alert("No match!");
  }

}
```